# import and export may only appear at the top level

Tags: angular

**import** and **export** may only appear at the top level but many developer has used it elsewhere in there code but *I am seeing an error in the same so on which condition can we use it in the middle of the code* and in which condition we should use it only at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import it at the top. Otherwise is a bad practice. It `should` work anyway, but the file will just be confusing to whoever has to maintain it.

Answer (score 0):

Its Best practice to place it on the top because its easy to find/figure out what we are importing .
Instead of putting it into middle which reduce readability/understanding of code.
Getting an Error in the case when it is not in DOM when required.